# The inverse of projection function is a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, inverse-function, map-projections, closed-map

I have this questione about the projection, be: 
$$\pi :X  \times Y \to X$$
if we consider $ \pi^{-1}(x): x \to x \times Y $

I want to know if this is a closed map, is easy to see that $\pi$ is not, but I don't see what happens with the inverse.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a function. Moreover $\pi$ is actually closed if $Y$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ is continuous.  Thus its inverse image of an open set is open and a closed set closed.  No, the inverse is not an open nor a closed map because it is not a map from X to X×Y.

It is a function from the power set of X to the power set of X×Y and those two power sets do not have a topology.  Thus it is meaningless to ask if its open or closed.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse projection takes x to the set {x} × Y which would only have a meaningful definition of open and closed in the power set of the product of X and Y. Topologies for power sets do exist, but I don't think you are looking for that avenue of thought.